# JPA: how to override collection table of element collection in subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

**Situation**: I have an abstract java class and two subclasses. The abstract class contains a collection of strings.
The two sub classes each has its own DB table, also the collection of strings in there should be saved in its own DB tables, depending on the subclass.
I am working with jpa element collection here. The setup is working fine for the ActiveResult class. But for the ArchivedResult, I could not work out how to override the collection table so that it can read from its own archived_result_values table.

**Result with this setup**: when reading from the ArchivedResult, it does not find the values of the collection, because it is trying to find them in the active_result_values table from the superclass instead of searching them in the archived_result_values table.

I hope it's possible without changing the Java classes (because I should not do so), so I am interested in how to change the hibernate orm.xml mapping accordingly.

*hint*: the real tables archived_result / active_result have some more (identical columns) but these are not relevant for the problem.

following java code

```
public abstract class AbstractResult {
  protected String Id;
  protected List<String> values;
}

public class ArchivedResult extends  AbstractResult {
  public ArchivedResult() {
    super();
  }
}

public class ActiveResult extends  AbstractResult {
  public ActiveResult() {
    super();
  }
}
```

here the orm.xml mappings

```
<entity-mappings .... >
  <mapped-superclass class="com.test.AbstractResult" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="Id">
            <column name="ar_id" />
        </id>
        
        <element-collection name="values" fetch="EAGER">
            <order-column name="item_index" />
            <column name="result_value" />
            <collection-table name="active_result_values">
                <join-column name="ar_id" />
            </collection-table>
        </element-collection>
        
    </attributes>
</mapped-superclass>
    
<entity name="ActiveResult" class="com.test.ActiveResult" access="FIELD">
    <table name="active_result" />
    <inheritance strategy="TABLE_PER_CLASS"/>
</entity>

<entity name="ArchivedResult" class="com.test.ArchivedResult"
        access="FIELD">
    <table name="archived_result" />
    <inheritance strategy="TABLE_PER_CLASS"/>
    <attributes>
        <element-collection name="values" fetch="EAGER">
            <order-column name="item_index" />
            <column name="result_value" />
            <collection-table name="archived_result_values">
                <join-column name="ar_id" />
            </collection-table>
        </element-collection>
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: I don't think overriding collection tables is possible. Probably better to map the collections separately for each class. If you need to access `getValues()` from the superclass, just make it abstract

Comment: thanks for the comment. that is right, this way is possible. I hoped there would be another way, but it seems not (at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the contract, define the getters and setters as abstract methods in the base class and implement them in the subclasses.

Comment: thanks, but thats basically the same what crizzy already mentioned, see my comment there.

Comment: On second thought, have you tried using the annotation model yet with `@AssociationOverride`? This might work for you, but no idea how to model this in hbm.xml

Comment: it is exactly the same as when you write that in xml.... and no, that does not work either, I tested this already.